# Noise Texture Glitch when using denoise

Tags: texturing, materials, denoise

[image]

Hey,everyone. I created a PBR FNaF plastic material and when I render it with low samples and use the Denoising feature,it blurs the Noise Texture and makes it really hard to see. It's supposed to look like the image above and not the one below. Can someone please tell me how to fix this without using high samples?

[image]

Comment: Denoise is great but is not the magic button. It might help you get an image with less noise at lower samples but at the expense of detail. How many samples are you using?

Comment: I'm using 32 samples. I used 1600 on a test render of my Ballora model,but it took too long. When I used 32 for it,the noise texture was horribly blurred.

Comment: 32 samples is way too low. Try at least 200

Comment: I did and it was still blurred. Maybe I should use 1024 or even 1250 samples,but the price for that is a slow render speed.

Comment: the price of sharpness is indeed lots of render samples...

Comment: Can you upload a `.blend` file or post a picture of your nodes?

Comment: Okay,I will. But after you help me,promise that you'll delete it afterwards. Capito?

Comment: I have another problem with the Noise Texture now. I'm trying to render a teaser for a FNaF fan game and every time I render the hat,the texture is blurred by the Denoising pass even when I'm using 4096 samples. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. A kind person on Reddit suggested that I should tweak with the settings and he was right. Like with Clamping,I noticed that the Denoising filter has Direct and Indirect settings,both of which are always turned on. I tweaked the Glossy pass of the Denoising filter and it helped me out a lot. To prevent the Noise texture from blurring,you have to turn off the Direct pass and leave the Indirect pass alone.

[image]